# How to select a time series model based on this ACF?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I think that I am missing some concepts because I am not able to model adequately this series.
It is a times series over 12 years.
I tried with multiple AR and MA models, nevertheless, I can't model it.
I am including the ACF for the series.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what went wrong? I am having difficulty interpreting what you mean by *"I can't model it"*.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like the ACF of a (short) MA process as it goes to zero too slowly. The next step would be to look at the partial autocorrelation function (PACF). If the PACF goes to zero reasonably fast this would indicate an AR process, otherwise you could try fitting some short ARMA models (and if that doesn't work well maybe a longer MA process). To me, based on just the ACF, it looks like an AR(2) or AR(3) model with one of the parameters negative could be a reasonable fit.